# This page isn't working File Submit Form

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am using FreeForm 4.1.3 and ExpressionEngine 2.7.3.  I have a form that was working for a while and I think I am running into an issue now.  I did have to recently go into EE settings and update my file upload location of my host.  I updated the Server Path to Upload Directory under CP Home -> File Manager -> File Upload Preferences -> Edit File Upload Preferences.  I guess the host of my client updated their hosting somewhere along the lines and now when I try to upload certain documents it knocks out my site....
In chrome I get...

This page isn’t working

www.xxxxxxxxx.com didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I am not sure what is going on.... I can back my page up and submit again with a txt file and it submits....just not a docx....I have file uploads set to all file types.

Comment: I am noticing I can do any file through file manager upload file but not docx.  I have past docx's in here so I know they used to work.  Any ideas where I can do this?  in my mimes.php file i have docx there and under security and session I have Apply XSS Filter to uploaded files set to Yes.

Comment: If you're confident that users won't upload malicious files turn off xss filtering.

Comment: When i turn off xss filtering I still have the issue of uploading docx files.  I get a weird broken image icon when I use the built in file manager and try to upload a docx.

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy moved me to a new server that has modsecurity on for docx, since it's a shared environment I cannot disable it to allow docx uploads....hope this helps someone else.